# SQL Server CE Cast/Convert Double to String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

This may seems like a stupid question for most, but it has been bugging me for quite a while.

How do we concat a string and an integer in SQL Server CE?

FYI, I am using Vb.Net and Visual Studio 2010 Query Builder.

I tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mi.qty) FROM MutationItem mi
```

and

```
SELECT CAST(qty AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Expr1 FROM MutationItem mi
```

and

```
SELECT CAST(qty AS VARCHAR) AS Expr1 FROM MutationItem mi
```

with no luck.

The latter gives me an error :

> Error in list of function arguments: 'AS' not recognized. Unable to
>   parse query text.

Please give me a hand on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it's my bad.

Or actually it's the wizard's bad.

So I tried to push it even though it gives me an error, and it worked eventually.

My guess is that the table relation designer cant replicate CAST or CONVERT, and then giving me an alert about that.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I skipped this problem Visual Studio create a function with the code which throws problems

for example this code sql on sybase

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetV(@cod NUMERIC(8)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result VARCHAR(20)
  DECLARE @query VARCHAR(100)
  SET @query = (SELECT p.v1+' '+cast(p.v2 AS VARCHAR)+'X'+cast(p.v3 AS VARCHAR) FROM table1 p WHERE p.cod=@cod)
  IF(@query IS NULL OR @query = '' OR @query = ' ')
    SET @result = 0
  ELSE
    SET @result = @query
  RETURN @result
END
GO
```